# Unchangable button width and height

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to resize a button programatically, but modifying the parameters gives no effect.

```
btnCancel = [UIButton buttonWithType:102];
[btnCancel setFrame:CGRectMake(22.0f, 7.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
[btnCancel setTitle:@"Anuluj" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnCancel setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[btnCancel addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelTyping) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Any idea why? i can give whatever amount i like to the parameters, but result is the same - width is bounded to text length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code and tested it in iOS 6.0. This is the final version of what you need to do

Add QuartzCore Library and add this to your header file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Now here's your button code with a pic. Play around with width and hight and they will change

```
UIButton *btnCancel =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnCancel setFrame:CGRectMake(22.0f, 7.0f, 80.0f, 80.0f)];
    [btnCancel setTitle:@"Anuluj" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnCancel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    btnCancel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    btnCancel.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
    btnCancel.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    [btnCancel addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelTyping) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

[image]

Comment: yes, but i want to get a blue and red button like here, http://teehanlax.com.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/buttons.png possibly without writing everything by hand

Comment: Or choose anyone of these projects https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=uibutton

Comment: thanks for great resources! im new to ios dev and i think it will be very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `btnCancel = [UIButton buttonWithType:102];` by `btnCancel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

Comment: i don't think this is a Problem with Type.. :(

Answer (score 0):

you almost certainly have autolayout turned on.  Go into interface builder and turn it off and your code should work

Comment: indeed it was turned on, but disabling it didnt help :(

Answer (score 0):

use `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]` with appropriate value, button will resize.

```
UIButtonTypeCustom = 0,
UIButtonTypeRoundedRect,
UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure,
UIButtonTypeInfoLight,
UIButtonTypeInfoDark,
UIButtonTypeContactAdd
```

Comment: yes, but i want to get a blue and red button like here, http://teehanlax.com.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/buttons.png possibly without writing everything by hand